# Android, awaiting all responses before displaying success or failure in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

My app is currently facing a problem, when there is a response error or a response is loading too slowly, the app will continue to load with some of this information missing. I have been trying to get the app to wait for all the responses to respond before either displaying an error or success, however, my newest implementation of the above concept is not working.

How can I make this work?

**ViewModel.kt**

```
##ViewModel
class NewsViewModel(var NewsRepositorys:NewsRepository) : ViewModel() {

//How the requests are made in the viewmodel. I was trying to make sure all the responses are finish before resuming the code hence the use of `await`
    suspend fun getNews(Country:String,Business: String?, Entertainment:String?, General:String?, Health:String?, Science:String?, Sports:String?,Tech:String?):MutableLiveData<Map<String, MutableList<Article>?>> {

    var maps =viewModelScope.async {

        var business = async{ NewsRepositorys.getNewsCall(Country, Business).value}
        var entertainment = async{NewsRepositorys.getNewsCall(Country, Entertainment).value}
        var general = async{NewsRepositorys.getNewsCall(Country, General).value}
        var health = async{NewsRepositorys.getNewsCall(Country, Health).value}
        var science = async{NewsRepositorys.getNewsCall(Country, Science).value}
        var sports = async{NewsRepositorys.getNewsCall(Country, Sports).value}
        var tech = async{NewsRepositorys.getNewsCall(Country, Tech).value}

        var newsMaps = mapOf(
            "Business" to business.await(),
            "Entertainment" to entertainment.await(),
            "General" to general.await(),
            "Health" to health.await(),
            "Science" to science.await(),
            "Sports" to sports.await(),
            "Tech" to tech.await()
        )
        return@async newsMaps
    }

    return MutableLiveData(maps.await())
}
...
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
//In the MainActivity class the companion objects of type `MutableList<Article>?` holds the `response` information for each respective category
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ...
        // Send request call for news data
        //Calling the requestNews function in the onCreate
        lifecycleScope.launch {
        requestNews("us")}
    }

}
    suspend private fun requestNews(country:String) {
        viewModel.getNews( Country = country, BUSINESS, ENTERTAINMENT, GENERAL, HEALTH, SCIENCE, SPORTS,
            TECHNOLOGY)?.observe(this) {

        BusinessNews = it["Business"]
        EntertainmentNews = it["Entertainment"]
        generalNews = it["General"]
        healthNews = it["Health"]
        ScienceNews = it["Science"]
        SportsNews = it["Sports"]
        TechNews = it["Tech"]


            if(apiRequestError == false){
                ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
                FragmentContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }else{
                ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
                FragmentContainer.visibility = View.GONE
                val showError: TextView = findViewById(R.id.display_error)
                showError.text = errorMessage
                showError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

    }
}
companion object{
    //var generalNews changed from ArrayList<NewsModel>
    var ScienceNews: MutableList<Article>? = mutableListOf()
    var EntertainmentNews: MutableList<Article>? = mutableListOf()
    var SportsNews: MutableList<Article>? = mutableListOf()
    var BusinessNews: MutableList<Article>? = mutableListOf()
    var healthNews: MutableList<Article>? = mutableListOf()
    var generalNews: MutableList<Article>? = mutableListOf()
    var TechNews: MutableList<Article>? = mutableListOf()
    var apiRequestError:Boolean = false

    var errorMessage = "error"
    var SocketTimeout: JSONException? = null
}

}
```

Comment: Please don't say "is not working". Describe the failure.